# Position MBProgressHUD at the Bottom/Top of the screen

Tags: ios, mbprogresshud

Is there a way to make the MBProgressHUD show at the bottom or top of the screen?

I have tried setting the frame using `[hud setFrame:....];`, `initWithFrame`, and setting the`center` property of the hud. None of these worked. I did an NSLog() of the frames after trying these methods. The values had changed but the hud still displayed at the center of the screen.

A thing to note, the hud is displayed using a UIWindow:

```
UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject];
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:window animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeText;
hud.labelText = @"some text";
```

Did this because the hud is displayed by a background execution block, thus the hud could be displayed on any view currently in display.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, we can change `MBProgressHUD` view location from center to the bottom or top.

Just add the `yOffset` property of the `MBProgressHUD` and you will get the exact location that you want.

Use :

```
MBProgressHUD *Hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] init];
hud.yOffset = 250.0; //For bottom location.
```

Comment: For Swift 4, hud.yOffset is deprecated. Use hud.offset.y instead.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same trouble with a [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/TransitApp/SVProgressHUD) turns out I just had to add a new method

```
+ (void)setOffsetFromCenter:(UIOffset)offset {
[self sharedView].offsetFromCenter = offset;
}
```

and call it when I showed the HUD

```
[SVProgressHUD setOffsetFromCenter:UIOffsetMake(0, 120)];
```

Mine just had to go a bit lower than mid-screen. Try it out, its a SingleTon so it's easier to call show and remove.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd have to make lots of changes to MBProgressHUD for this to work. Can't do changes since I'm using pods.

Comment: Top answer states you can change that, I must recommend you use this singleton.

Answer (score 1):

We can change position of `MBProgressHUD` via change in  `yOffset` and `xOffset`.
Below line of code is for place  `MBProgressHUD` at bottom.

```
let hud = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: view, animated: true)
hud?.mode = .text
hud?.labelText = json!["message"] as! String
hud?.yOffset = Float(view.frame.size.height*2/5);
hud?.removeFromSuperViewOnHide = true
hud?.margin = 10.0
hud?.hide(true, afterDelay: 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

for **Swift 4** , changed `hud.offset.x` and `hud.offset.y`

```
let hud = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.annularDeterminate
hud.offset.y = 10
hud.offset.x = 10
```

Answer (score -1):

No its not posible to change the position of MBProgressHUD to top or bottom.refer this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-uiactivityindicatorview-and-mbprogresshud--mobile-10530)